# How to secure access token beyond XSS and CSRF

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, access-token, packet-sniffers

I understand the XSS vulnerability of using web storage and the CSRF vulnerability of using cookies. So I store the access token in memory and for persistence I have a refresh token in a cookie which I use to silently refresh my access token when we lose it. I feel somewhat better about XSS and CSRF threats... **BUT how do we secure the token from a packet sniffer? A packet sniffer would find the token in the request.** I see a lot of discussion on XSS and CSRF but how do we keep safe from packet sniffers, and are there even more threats we do not commonly think about?

Comment: Is https not enough to encrypt data from packet sniffers ?

Comment: I am really not sure, but I did some stuff over HTTPS while messing in Azure Portal - and I had Fiddler running. I can clearly see the access token in the header from within Fiddler. I am hoping someone with more knowledge can help me understand this. I suspect someone is going to say something like 'if they are on your network then this is a much more severe breach compared to remote javascript injection or CSRF, and you would expect greater exposure'. But then what's the point of HTTPS if we can do this? There is a gap in my knowledge right there.

Comment: added an answer hopefully to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use HTTPS to defend against packet sniffers.

Fiddler as a proxy will not be able to decrypt HTTPS traffic in the cloud unless the fiddlers built in root certificate is added to the browser or client making the request.

Fiddler is able to decrypt HTTPS because you have added Fiddlers root certificate to your trusted store in YOUR computer. without this a proper HTTPS connections can't be made.

So , don't worry about Fidler in the cloud.

Comment: That was the key step I was forgetting - the part where I added Fiddler's root certificate to my trusted store and that's why I can trace those calls. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https provides an end to end encryption. Its implenented on the application level by browsers so no other users on the same network doesnt break https security.

The below is a short explanation of how ssl and https (http over ssl) works

Ssl:

The key idea is that mathematically you can generate a public key A and a private key B in a way that if you encrypt something with A you can only decrypt it with B.
So let's say the server google has a pair of  public key A and private key B.
A client wants to send some data to google. The idea is if the client has key B he can encrypt the data he wants to send and he doesnt care anymore of network threats such as a man in the middle fishing the packet or data because only the owner of key B (google) can decrypt the data. So the man in the middle will only have encrypted data which has no use.
Note that from above it is clear that servers (google here) should keep their private key unshared, but should distribute their public key so that clients can use to communicate safely (with encryption) with the server.

How to distribute the public key ?

Using the public key infrastructure (PKI) which is a set of roles, entities, definitions, etc. used to manage and distribute public keys.

Again in short, a server request a certificate from a certificate authority (CA). That certificate contains information on the server (name, ip, etc.) And the public key and private key generated for that server (note here there are several procedures that a server might request to generate the keys, one of which is the server generates the private key and the CA only responsible for generating the public key).

Finally, there is a list of trusted CAs built into the browsers, so that these browsers such as chrome can go to and get google's public key A, and use it to encrypt the data it wants to send to google.

The above is how ssl communication protocol works (ssl certificates). Ssl is simply a protocol that provides secure communication. It provides no routing and networking capabilities.

Https:

Https is basically HTTP connection which is delivering the data secured using SSL.
That means SSL encrypted data will be routed using protocols like HTTP for communication.